# Log4Net problem on IIS 7.5 in Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, log4net, iis-7.5

I have a WCF service running on Windows 2008 R2 64 bit, using IIS 7.5. My appender is logging to a local file, and on my XP workstation a log file is being created in the application folder.

Log4NEt is not logging anything on the server.

I have tried the following:

- Ensured that my application pool is running as a domain user account. Added that account to the "administrators" group of the server.
- Granted "Everyone" modify permissions on the application folder on the server.
- Changed the appender to output to c:\logs\logfile.txt, and granted "Everyone" full control of that folder.
- Set the log4net to "debug", and used DebugView to see if it is outputting any messages. There were NO log4net messages shown
- Added an app setting <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>

Any ideas what else I can try to try and figure out what is going on? There are no messages in the system event log that look like they relate to this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you starting log4net on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an issue. there is a log on log4net issue tracking tool with similar problem.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-266

Answer (score 1):

When log4net is not logging it is usually due to it not being configured.

Try checking "LogManager.GetRepository().Configured" value just before the first log statement you think should be logged, but isnt.